# C++ Win32 How to Create a "toggle" Pushbutton

Tags: c++, winapi, button, toggle

I was originally thinking this would be extremely easy to do. Google searches returned results for everything but this.

I am trying to have a normal button that I can click, and it stays down, click again, and it rises back up.

I found one function that did what I wanted, but only worked if the button retained focus, click anywhere else and it rises again.

`Button_SetState(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_BTN_SLEEPCLICK), TRUE);`

Is there any real way to do this? Or am I gonna need to do this kind of thing by hand?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a check box, then set the "push like" property for that check box to true.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, this is what it looks like:
`hButtonSleep = CreateWindowEx(0, "BUTTON", "Sleep Click", 
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE,
                0, 0, 40, 19, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_BTN_SLEEPCLICK, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);`

Answer (score 2):

You want a checkbox with `BS_PUSHLIKE` style. To toggle it programmatically, use `Button_SetCheck`

Answer (score 1):

The "staying down" and "rising back up" are a matter of how you draw the button.

You could create your own button class by using the Paint and Redraw methods.