# How to implement a Snipping Tool like split button in MFC?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I want to create a split button using MFC which behaves the same as the drawing pen button of Snipping Tool in Windows (the button circled in red below).

[image]

For keeping a `CButton` in pushed state after click, it can be easily done by setting style with following code ([C++ Win32 How to Create a "toggle" Pushbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369721/c-win32-how-to-create-a-toggle-pushbutton/18369792)) :

`button.SetButtonStyle(BS_CHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE)`

Intuitively, I believe there should be simple API calls to make it work. I tried to use `CSplitButton` to do what Snipping Tool achieved. However, I was unable to find any simple way to achieve my goal. Currently, I want to avoid implementing the my own split button with the complicated `DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)`.

I have tried to use `CButton::SetState(BOOL bHighlight)` inside `OnBnClickedSplit` function. I can keep the button highlighted until

1. user clicks the button,
2. user clicks other controls,
3. or user clicks area outside the program.

```cpp
int MySnippingTool::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    //...

    m_splitBtnPen.Create(NULL, WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP|BS_PUSHBUTTON|BS_ICON, rect, this, IDC_SPLITBUTTON_PEN);
    hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON_PEN),IMAGE_ICON, 0,0,0);
    m_splitBtnPen.SetIcon(hIcon);
    m_splitBtnPen.SetState(TRUE);

    //...
}

void MySnippingTool::OnBnClickedSplit()
{
    // This button click method will be triggered when this button or
    // other controls is clicked. Or user clicks area outside the program
    m_pressed = !m_pressed;
    if (m_pressed )
        m_splitBtnPen.SetState(TRUE);
    else
        m_splitBtnPen.SetState(FALSE);

    OutputDebugStringA(m_pressed ? "Pressed On\n" : "Pressed Off\n");
}
```

But it is still not I want. I think the reason has been mentioned in MSDN.

> A button control is automatically highlighted when the user clicks and
>   holds the left mouse button. The highlighting is removed when the user
>   releases the mouse button.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebw1hfe8.aspx

Do anyone know any API call would be make it work? Is there any simple way to do it? Or I must implement the whole split button and `DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)` by my own?

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I have run through the sample you give me and also read the API again about **CButton** and **CSplitButton**. I also look into how these two classes implemented in VC2008, VC2010 **VC\atlmfc\src** folder. Both look and view for CButton & CSplitButton are hidden inside Win32 API call CreateEx(). There are no implementation for OnDraw() or DrawItem() for both classes in the **atlmfc** folder. It seems that I need to implement either OnDraw() or DrawItem in custom split button in order to have split button pushed effect for style similar to `BS_CHECKBOX | BS_PUSHLIKE`

Comment: I am also considering doing the work under ground by adding control to the message received by the window who owns the split button. May be trick the split button that the mouse does not release the button and keep holding the button.

Comment: Did you try with a `CMFCMenuButton` instead? Important note: In this case your dialog class should be derived from `CDialogEx`!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create an image based CSplitterButton derived control with image based pull-down menus which looks like this:
[image]

You need to create a custom made class derived from CSplitButton.

```
class SGSplitImageButton : public CSplitButton
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(SGSplitImageButton)

public:
    SGSplitImageButton();
    virtual ~SGSplitImageButton();
    CMenu *menu;

    void InsertMenu(CString title, UINT imgId, UINT menuID);
    void SetDropDown();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
};
```

See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5303076/CSplitButon-with-images) article.

Comment: Excellent answer !